How can metagenomic analysis be used to determine the native habitat of a bacterial species?
Background
A native habitat refers to the natural environment in which a particular species or organism has evolved and to which it is best adapted.
In the context of bacteria or other microorganisms, a native habitat might include specific soil types, plant surfaces, animal hosts, or aquatic environments where the organism naturally occurs and forms part of the ecosystem.
Metagenomic analysis refers to the study and analysis of genetic material recovered directly from environmental samples, bypassing the need for culturing individual species in a laboratory. This technique allows scientists to explore the diversity of microbial communities, including bacteria, viruses, fungi, and other microorganisms, within a given environment.
Question
How can metagenomic analysis be used to determine the native habitat of a bacterial species?
Prior self-work
Disclaimer: I have been searching for an introductory text on this matter for almost a week now with no hope. All I find is applications in the form of research studies that didn't, as expected, give any introduction on the matter, specifically with satisfactory details.

In biotechnological water treatment assays, it's common to correlate certain species of bacteria or protozoans with a score to determine if the water is safe to drink or not or whether it has to go for further processing, etc...
A similar principle is used in metagenomic analysis but contrasting DNA samples recovered from the environment against known DNA sequences of bacteria/fungi/virus in databases. It's like DNA barcoding. There is the added complexity of also having to log the different physical aspects of each sample collection, and it seems that this review from 2024 concludes that there's still work to be done.

References:
Roy G, Prifti E, Belda E, Zucker JD. Deep learning methods in metagenomics: a review. Microb Genom. 2024 Apr;10(4):001231. doi: 10.1099/mgen.0.001231. PMID: 38630611; PMCID: PMC11092122
National Research Council (US) Committee on Metagenomics: Challenges and Functional Applications. The New Science of Metagenomics: Revealing the Secrets of Our Microbial Planet. Washington (DC): National Academies Press (US); 2007. 1, Why Metagenomics?
